# How to find the minimum posn-x in a list of positions in scheme

Tags: scheme

Hi I'm having trouble using beginner with list abbreviations in a scheme and I dont know how to find the minimum posn-x given a list of make-posns. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to write a function that finds the minimum in a list of numbers?

Comment: I know how to write the function that finds the min of alon but i dont know how to turn posn-xs from a list of positions into a list of numbers

Comment: (map posn-x lop)  where lop is a list of posns.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation of the discussion in the comments:

```
(define (min-x lst)
   (apply min (map posn-x lst)))
```